# Existe alguma biblioteca ou plugin PHP para validação de campos?

Tags: php, validação, biblioteca

Existe alguma biblioteca, plugin ou algo que deixe mais fácil e prático a tarefa de validar campos, string e etc?

Ex: tenho que pegar o nome de usuário,e como é um nome só aceitará letras (e espaços), algo do tipo:

```
$validateFields = new validateFields;
$userName = $validateFields->validateName($_POST['name']);
$userPass = ....
$userPhone = .....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Respect Validation

> The most awesome validation engine ever created for PHP

Traduzindo:

> O motor de validação mais impressionante já criado para PHP

Realmente eu concordo. Os caras pensaram em tudo quando fizeram essa biblioteca. Essa biblioteca possui validação para inúmeros tipos de dados: cpf, cnh, cnpj, numérico, vogais, máximo, mínimo, não-vazio, etc.

Se eu não me engano, eles têm uma grande contribuição de programadores brasileiros.

Veja como instalar (você precisa do Composer):

```
composer require respect/validation
```

Link do [repositório no Github](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

[Aqui](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) você tem vários exemplos de como usar.

Vou mostrar um exemplo tirado da própria documentação:

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

$user = new stdClass;
$user->name = 'Alexandre';
$user->birthdate = '1987-07-01';

$userValidator = v::attribute('name', v::stringType()->length(1,32))
                  ->attribute('birthdate', v::date()->age(18));

$userValidator->validate($user); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, vou dar uma testada